# SSLException from AwsSDK S3AsyncClient GetObjectRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using a software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest to retrieve an object in a S3AsyncClient getObject method call from an enterprise S3 instance that emulates AWS S3 functionality. This follows the pattern of Baeldung aws-s3-reactive demo found at
https://www.baeldung.com/java-aws-s3-reactive

The above-mentioned demo was converted from maven to gradle and integrated into an existing project (demo is part of a much bigger tutorial project).

Executing the S3AsyncClient getObject call resulted in exception of "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already". Debugging the call using the logger produced the below output. I have to wonder if there are missing headers, or if I am missing something else. The more tranditional AmazonS3.getObject call works and produces a few select headers not included in this S3AsyncClient.getObject.

I share the output (edited to remove personal information), relevant configuration classes, and services below for both the S3AsyncClient getObject call (unsuccessful) and AmazonS3 getObject call (successful) below, with the build.gradle file at the bottom. Any input as to what I may be doing wrong with the

S3AyncClient.getObject (unsuccessful) output ("DEBUG***" denotes lines that begin with:
"DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:147 - [id: {id}, L:{ip}:{port} - R:{namespace}.{endpoint}/{ip:port}]"):

```
GET /mybucket/resource.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: {namespace}.{endpoint:port}
amz-sdk-invocation-id: {invocation-id}
amz-sdk-retry: 0/0/
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={namespace}-user01/20200831/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature={signature}
User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/2.10.86 Windows_10/10.0 Java_HotSpot_TM__64-Bit_Server_VM/25.191-b12 Java/1.8.0_191 vendor/Oracle_Corporation io/async http/UNKNOWN
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Date: 20200831T203041Z


 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** FLUSH
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-2] DEBUG*** READ COMPLETE
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-2] DEBUG*** INACTIVE
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** FLUSH
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-2] DEBUG*** UNREGISTERED
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** WRITE, DefaultHttpContent(data: EmptyByteBufBE, decoderResult: success), 0B
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** FLUSH
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure)
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** WRITE, EmptyLastHttpContent, 0B
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** FLUSH
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request:84 - Retryable error detected. Will retry in 18ms. Request attempt number 2
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** READ COMPLETE
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** INACTIVE
 [aws-java-sdk-NettyEventLoop-0-4] DEBUG*** UNREGISTERED
 [sdk-ScheduledExecutor-2-0] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request:84 - Retrying Request: DefaultSdkHttpFullRequest(httpMethod=GET, protocol=https, host={namespace}.{endpoint}, port={port}, encodedPath=/mybucket/resource.pdf, headers=[amz-sdk-invocation-id, User-Agent], queryParameters=[])


>> DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:147 - [id: {id}] REGISTERED
>> DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:147 - [id: {id}] CONNECT: {namespace}.{endpoint}/{ip:port}
>> DEBUG*** ACTIVE
>> DEBUG*** WRITE: software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.NettyRequestExecutor$StreamedRequest(DefaultHttpRequest(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1)


GET /mybucket/resource.pdf HTTP/1.1
Host: {namespace}.{endpoint:port}
amz-sdk-invocation-id: {invocation-id}
amz-sdk-retry: {retry}
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={namespace}-user01/20200831/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-retry;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature={signature}
User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/2.10.86 Windows_10/10.0 Java_HotSpot_TM__64-Bit_Server_VM/25.191-b12 Java/1.8.0_191 vendor/Oracle_Corporation io/async http/UNKNOWN
x-amz-content-sha256: UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Date: 20200831T203044Z)


***{{{{ below lines prior to stack trace begin with: 
"DEBUG io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:147 - [id: {id}, L:{ip}:{port} - R:{namespace}.{endpoint}/{ip:port}]" }}}}

>> DEBUG*** FLUSH
>> DEBUG*** FLUSH
>> DEBUG*** WRITE, DefaultHttpContent(data: EmptyByteBufBE, decoderResult: success), 0B
>> DEBUG*** FLUSH
>> DEBUG*** USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure)
>> DEBUG*** WRITE, EmptyLastHttpContent, 0B
>> DEBUG*** FLUSH
>> DEBUG*** READ COMPLETE
>> DEBUG*** INACTIVE
>> DEBUG*** UNREGISTERED
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:837)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:800)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:781)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:533)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.flush(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:741)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:727)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.flush(LoggingHandler.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:789)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:757)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HttpStreamsHandler.completeBody(HttpStreamsHandler.java:332)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HttpStreamsHandler.access$400(HttpStreamsHandler.java:43)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HttpStreamsHandler$3$1.run(HttpStreamsHandler.java:310)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HttpStreamsHandler.executeInEventLoop(HttpStreamsHandler.java:376)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HttpStreamsHandler.access$300(HttpStreamsHandler.java:43)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HttpStreamsHandler$3.complete(HttpStreamsHandler.java:307)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerSubscriber$3.operationComplete(HandlerSubscriber.java:274)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerSubscriber$3.operationComplete(HandlerSubscriber.java:271)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:570)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:549)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:608)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PromiseNotificationUtil.tryFailure(PromiseNotificationUtil.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:57)
    at io.netty.channel.DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.operationComplete(DelegatingChannelPromiseNotifier.java:31)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.releaseAndCompleteAll(AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.releaseAndFailAll(AbstractCoalescingBufferQueue.java:207)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.releaseAndFailAll(SslHandler.java:1822)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1801)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handleUnwrapThrowable(SslHandler.java:1263)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1233)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1274)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Aug 31, 2020 4:30:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: SSLEngine closed already] with root cause
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already
{rest of stack trace is exactly the same as above}
```

The GET method, S3ClientConfiguration class, and S3ClientConfigurationProperties class are shared below.

DownloadResource (unsuccessful). Attempted GET call goes through downloadFile

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inbox")
@Slf4j
public class DownloadResource {


    private final S3AsyncClient s3client;
    private final S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3config;

    public DownloadResource(S3AsyncClient s3client, S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3config) {
        this.s3client = s3client;
        this.s3config = s3config;
    }


    @GetMapping(path="/{filekey}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<ByteBuffer>>> downloadFile(@PathVariable("filekey") String filekey) {

        GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(s3config.getBucket())
                .key(filekey)
                .build();

        return Mono.fromFuture(s3client.getObject(request,new FluxResponseProvider()))
                .map( (response) -> {
                    checkResult(response.sdkResponse);
                    String filename = getMetadataItem(response.sdkResponse,"filename",filekey);

                    log.info("[I65] filename={}, length={}",filename, response.sdkResponse.contentLength() );

                    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, response.sdkResponse.contentType())
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(response.sdkResponse.contentLength()))
                            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"")
                            .body(response.flux);
                });
    }

    /**
     * Lookup a metadata key in a case-insensitive way.
     * @param sdkResponse
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    private String getMetadataItem(GetObjectResponse sdkResponse, String key, String defaultValue) {
        for( Entry<String, String> entry : sdkResponse.metadata().entrySet()) {
            if ( entry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }


    // Helper used to check return codes from an API call
    private static void checkResult(GetObjectResponse response) {
        SdkHttpResponse sdkResponse = response.sdkHttpResponse();
        if ( sdkResponse != null && sdkResponse.isSuccessful()) {
            return;
        }

        throw new DownloadFailedException(response);
    }


    static class FluxResponseProvider implements AsyncResponseTransformer<GetObjectResponse,FluxResponse> {

        private FluxResponse response;

        @Override
        public CompletableFuture<FluxResponse> prepare() {
            response = new FluxResponse();
            return response.cf;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(GetObjectResponse sdkResponse) {
            this.response.sdkResponse = sdkResponse;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStream(SdkPublisher<ByteBuffer> publisher) {
            response.flux = Flux.from(publisher);
            response.cf.complete(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionOccurred(Throwable error) {
            response.cf.completeExceptionally(error);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Holds the API response and stream
     * @author Philippe
     */
    static class FluxResponse {

        final CompletableFuture<FluxResponse> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
        GetObjectResponse sdkResponse;
        Flux<ByteBuffer> flux;
    }

}
```

Configuration Properties Class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws.s3")
@Data
public class S3ClientConfigurationProperties {

    private Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    private URI endpoint;

    private     String accessKey;
    private String secretKey;

    // Bucket name we'll be using as our backend storage
    private String bucket;

    // AWS S3 requires that file parts must have at least 5MB, except
    // for the last part. This may change for other S3-compatible services, so let't
    // define a configuration property for that
    private int multipartMinPartSize = 5*1024*1024;

}
```

S3ClientConfiguration (unsuccessful)

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(S3ClientConfigurationProperties.class)
public class S3ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public S3AsyncClient s3client(S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3props, AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {

        SdkAsyncHttpClient httpClient = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
                .writeTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
                .maxConcurrency(64)
                .build();

        S3Configuration serviceConfiguration = S3Configuration.builder()
                .checksumValidationEnabled(false)
                .chunkedEncodingEnabled(true)
                .build();

        S3AsyncClientBuilder b = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                .httpClient(httpClient)
                .region(s3props.getRegion())
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .serviceConfiguration(serviceConfiguration);

        if (s3props.getEndpoint() != null) {
            b = b.endpointOverride(s3props.getEndpoint());
        }

        return b.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider(S3ClientConfigurationProperties s3props) {

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(s3props.getAccessKey())) {
            // Return default provider
            return DefaultCredentialsProvider.create();
        }
        else {
            // Return custom credentials provider
            return () -> {
                AwsCredentials creds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(s3props.getAccessKey(), s3props.getSecretKey());
                return creds;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

For comparison, here is output for (successful) AmazonS3.getObject call:

```
 >> "HEAD /mybucket/ HTTP/1.1"
 >> "Host: {namespace}.{endpoint:port}"
 >> "Authorization: AWS {namespace}-user01:{sig}="
 >> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.415 Windows_10/10.0 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.191-b12 java/1.8.0_191"
 >> "amz-sdk-invocation-id: {invocation-id}"
 >> "amz-sdk-retry: 0/0/500"
 >> "Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:27:43 GMT"
 >> "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive"
 
 
 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
 << "Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:27:43 GMT"
 << "Server: ViPR/1.0"
 << "x-amz-request-id: {request-id}"
 << "x-amz-id-2: {id}"
 << "x-emc-retention-period: 0"
 << "Content-Length: 0"
 << ""
 
 
 >> "GET /mybucket/Calendar HTTP/1.1"
 >> "Host: {namespace}.{endpoint:port}"
 >> "Authorization: AWS {namespace}-user01:{sig}"
 >> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.415 Windows_10/10.0 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.191-b12 java/1.8.0_191"
 >> "amz-sdk-invocation-id: {invocation-id}"
 >> "amz-sdk-retry: 0/0/500"
 >> "Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:27:44 GMT"
 >> "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
 >> "Content-Length: 0"
 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive"
 >> ""
 
 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
 << "Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 20:27:44 GMT"
 << "Cache-Control: no-cache"
 << "Server: ViPR/1.0"
 << "x-amz-request-id: {request-id}"
 << "x-amz-id-2: {amz-id-2}"
 << "ETag: "d9b5afd94610a7578384af7b36186b94""
 << "Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Aug 2020 15:38:29 GMT"
 << "x-emc-mtime: 1598542709166"
 << "x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256"
 << "Content-Type: application/pdf"
 << "Content-Length: 44255"
```

AmazonS3.getObject (successful) method call is as seen below:

```
    public S3Object get(String key) {
        return s3Storage.getClient().getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3Storage.getBucket(), key));
    }
```

S3Configuration (successful):

```
@Configuration
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class S3Configuration {

    @Bean
    public S3Storage s3Storage(S3ServiceInfo s3ServiceInfo) {
        final ClientConfiguration httpsClientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS).withSignerOverride("S3SignerType");
        httpsClientConfig.getApacheHttpClientConfig().setSslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory());

        AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
            .withClientConfiguration(httpsClientConfig)
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(s3ServiceInfo.getAccessKey(), s3ServiceInfo.getSecretKey())))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(endpointUrlWithNamespace(s3ServiceInfo.getEndpoint(), s3ServiceInfo.getAccessKey()), null))
            .build();

        return new S3Storage(client, s3ServiceInfo.getBucket(), s3ServiceInfo.getEndpoint());
    }

    protected String endpointUrlWithNamespace(String endpoint, String accessKey) {
        //extract namespace from access-key (verify format)
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("((.+?-){3}ns\\d\\d)-").matcher(accessKey);
        if (!matcher.find()) return endpoint;
        String namespace = matcher.group(1);

        return endpoint.contains("://s3-object") ? endpoint.replace("://", "://" + namespace + ".") : endpoint;
    }


    @Configuration
    @Profile("cloud")
    @Import(CloudScanConfiguration.class)
    public class S3CloudConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {
        @Bean
        public S3ServiceInfo s3ServiceInfo() {
            return (S3ServiceInfo)cloud().getServiceInfos(S3ServiceInfo.class).get(0);
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @Profile("!cloud")
    public class S3LocalConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public S3ServiceInfo s3ServiceInfo(
                @Value("${aws.s3.accessKey}") String accessKey,
                @Value("${aws.s3.secretKey}") String secretKey,
                @Value("${aws.s3.bucket}") String bucket,
                @Value("${aws.s3.endpoint}") String endpoint) {

            return new S3ServiceInfo(null, accessKey, secretKey, endpoint, bucket);
        }
    }


    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class S3Storage {
        private AmazonS3 client;
        private String bucket;
        private String endpoint;
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.1.RELEASE'
        awsSdkVersion = '2.10.86'
        springVersion = '5.2.6.RELEASE'
        springCloudVersion = 'Greenwich.RELEASE'
        springCloudServicesVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'

        lombokVersion = '1.18.10'
        junitJupiterVersion ='5.2.0'

        orgSlf4jVersion = '1.7.30'
        logbackVersion = '1.2.3'
        junitVersion ='4.12'
        junitPlatformVersion ='1.2.0'
        mavenSurefirePluginVersion = '2.15'
        hamcrestVersion = '2.2'
        hamcrestAllVersion = '1.3'
        mockitoVersion = '3.3.0'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
    id 'gradle-boost' version '2.0.0'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
}



configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
    exclude group: 'org.logback'

    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'logback-classic'
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springCloudServicesVersion}"
        mavenBom "software.amazon.awssdk:bom:${awsSdkVersion}"
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'


    //other
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'


    //aws
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:2.2.7'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.11.666'

    /*********** TEST ***********/

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:${springVersion}"
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    /************************************ log 4J2 ************************************/
    compileOnly  group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.11.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-web', version: '2.11.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-jcl', version: '2.11.1'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-1.2-api', version: '2.11.1'

    /********************************************************* apache *********************************************************/
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.6.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'


    compile "software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.10.27"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "software.amazon.awssdk:s3:${awsSdkVersion}"
    compile "software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:${awsSdkVersion}"
    testCompile "io.projectreactor:reactor-test:3.3.9.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springCloudServicesVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}"


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when copying objects at high rate, this is the configuration I ended up with

```
S3AsyncClient.builder() 
   .httpClientBuilder( NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder() 
       .connectionMaxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(180)) 
       .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) 
       .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120)) .maxConcurrency(120) 
       .maxPendingConnectionAcquires(50000)
   ) 
    .overrideConfiguration( ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder() 
        .retryPolicy( RetryPolicy.builder() 
           .backoffStrategy(BackoffStrategy.defaultStrategy()) 
           .throttlingBackoffStrategy(BackoffStrategy.defaultThrottlingStrategy()) 
           .numRetries(5) 
           .retryCondition(RetryCondition.defaultRetryCondition()) 
.build() 
) 
.apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120)) .build()) .build();
```

The API call attempt timeout is the amount of time to wait for the HTTP request to complete before timing out.